# Non-capturing groups in Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am matching a string in Javascript against the following regex:

```
(?:new\s)(.*)(?:[:])
```

The string I use the function on is "new Tag:var;"
What it suppod to return is only "Tag" but instead it returns an array containing "new Tag:" and the desired result as well.

I found out that I might need to use a lookbehind instead but since it is not supported in Javascript I am a bit lost.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't really get why you make such a complicated regexp for what you want to extract:

```
(?:new\\s)(.*)(?:[:])
```

whereas it can be solved using the following:

```
s = "new Tag:";
var out = s.replace(/new\s([^:]*):.*;/, "$1")
```

where you got only one capturing group which is the one you're looking for.

Comment: and as @anubhava states, `.*` is "greedy" and not a good idea, because if you got two or more columns in your string, it may match only the last one.

Comment: That overly greedy operator was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

- `\\s` (double escaping) is only needed for creating `RegExp` instance.
- Also your regex is using greedy pattern in `.*` which may be matching more than desired.

Make it non-greedy:

```
(?:new\s)(.*?)(?:[:])
```

OR better use negation:

```
(?:new\s)([^:]*)(?:[:])
```

Comment: My bad, the extra '\' was for escaping.
Otherwise, string.match() still returns an array containing two entries